# Mysql trigger creation bad syntax

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm trying to create a SQL Trigger, but i receive always an error message, i want to check on **update** and **insert** operation if value called **status** is not higher than 1 and not lower than 0.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ins_cert_login 
BEFORE UPDATE ON cert_login 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE errorMessage VARCHAR(255);
    SET errorMessage('Invalid Status Value.');
    
    IF new.status <> 0 AND new.status <> 1 THEN
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = errorMessage;
    END IF;
END
```

When i try to run the commands it returns error.
I'm using MySql.

The error:
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5`

Any hint?

Comment: edited post, sorry, was not higher than 1 and not lower than 0, my bad. posted error @Akina

Comment: Are you setting delimiters? What ide are you using?

Comment: SET statement syntax differs from used one. Must be `SET errorMessage := 'Invalid Status Value.';`. *not higher than 1 and not lower than 0* This is `new.status IN (0, 1)` for integer column and `new.status BETWEEN 0 AND 1` for non-integer column. *When i try to run the commands it returns error.* Show full error message text.

Comment: MESSAGE_TEXT is invalid on its own , its part of signal statement see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html

Comment: @P.Salmon i saw the documentation and added a SIGNAL SQLSTATE, but the error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message_text should be part of signal sqlstate following syntaxes on my box

```
drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER t 
BEFORE UPDATE ON cert_login 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE errorMessage VARCHAR(255);
    SET errorMessage = ('Invalid Status Value.');
    
    IF new.status <> 0 AND new.status <> 1 THEN
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = errorMessage;
    END IF;
END   $$

delimiter ;
```

and https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/913nweKrHqXL5SViuuqAZE/0

ps your first set statement is invalid you missed the =